# Type CallerMemberNameAttribute exists in both System.Runtime 2.6.10 and mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a Class Library running on `.Net 4.7`. Attempting to upgrade this project to and SDK style i take the following steps in a terminal window (Im using Visual Studio 2022) and keep the target to 4.7

```
dotnet tool install --global Project2015To2017.Migrate2019.Tool

dotnet migrate-2019 wizard proj.csproj
```

(Received an error about the runtime not being installed on my machine so clicked the link and installed.)

I get some messages but no real errors as such e.g.

*A better way to reference 'System.ComponentModel.Composition' assembly is using respective 'System.ComponentModel.Composition' NuGet package. It will simplify porting to other runtimes and enable possible .NET SDK tooling improvements.*

and

*Consider migrating to 'portable' debug type, cross-platform alternative to legacy Windows PDBs.*

Number of these types of messages appear.

I load up the solution in VS 2022 and try to rebuild but some NuGet package errors occur so i restore all packages using the `Nuget restore` command.

Im now faced with the error

***The type 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' exists in both System.Runtime VErsion 2.6.10.0 and mscorlib Version 4.0.0.0***

This occurs on the line

```
public void DoSomething([CallerMemberName] string nm = "")
{}
```

Ive tried to reference this explicitly i.e. `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName` but that didnt work and not entirely sure what i could attempt to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried "the usual" - restarting VS, deleting bin and obj folders, rebooting the machine?

Comment: Also check the csproj for explicit references to aforementioned nuget.

Comment: Yes restarted etc in the csproj i see a 'PackageReference' with System.Runtime version 4.3.1, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Try deleting it.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt resolve. I tried doing a search for System.Runtime 2.6.10.0 but that doesnt exist in the csproj file, the only link that did exist was the PackageReference v 4.3.1 which ive deleted

Comment: See if any other similar packages are installed and try removing them, may be one of the references the one in question.

Comment: Deleted any PackageReference that started with System.Runtime, closed VS, restarted but still didnt work. Same error